# MFC: Retrieving dropped data as if they were a file

Tags: file, winapi, com, mfc, drag-and-drop

**How do I retrieve global data from a drop operation as if these data were a file?** As far as I could find out (on the Internet and in [Jeff Procise's "Programming Windows with MFC (2nd ed.)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950), `COleDataObject::GetFileData` should be the answer, but I'm doing something wrong, given that the MFC `CFile` object is created but with an "invalid handle" value (-1).

I'm in fact trying to transfer virtual files (those that don't physically exist on a local drive) between two instance of my application. The transfer works fine between my application and the Windows Explorer (or similar) via HDROP and API [DragQueryFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776408(v=vs.85).aspx) (aka if exporting or importing a physical file).

This is the code that initiates the drag (using CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS formats to transfer virtual files that don't physically exist on a local disk):

```
// - allocate and fill in the FileGroupDescriptor structure
HGLOBAL hg=::GlobalAlloc( GHND|GMEM_SHARE, ... );
LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR pfgd=::GlobalLock(hg);
    ...
::GlobalUnlock(hg);
// - create an IDataObject instance and put the FileGroupDescriptor     structure into it
// (it holds that cfDescriptor=::RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR) )
CCustOleDataSource obj=... // COleDataSource-derived object
FORMATETC etcFileGroupDescriptor={ cfDescriptor, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
obj.CacheGlobalData( cfDescriptor, hg, &etcFileGroupDescriptor );
// - render the actual data upon request
// (it holds that cfContent=::RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS) )
FORMATETC etcFileContents={ cfContent, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
obj.DelayRenderFileData( cfContent, &etcFileContents );
// - perform drag&drop
obj.DoDragDrop(DROPEFFECT_COPY|DROPEFFECT_MOVE);
```

This is the code that accepts the drop (works fine if data is retrieved via `COleDataObject::GetGlobalData` but doesn't function when `COleDataObject::GetFileData` is used):

```
// - get the FileGroupDescriptor structure
HGLOBAL hg=pDataObject->GetGlobalData(cfDescriptor);
LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR pfgd=(LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR)::GlobalLock(hg);
// - get a CFile abstraction of the actual data
FORMATETC etcFileContents={ cfContent, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, 0, TYMED_ISTREAM }; // 0 = first dropped file
CFile *f=pDataObject->GetFileData( cfContent, &etcFileContents );
// Problem: "f" created but CFile::m_hFile equals INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
// - read one sample byte
BYTE b;
f->Read(&b,1);
// - delete the file object
delete f;
```

Yet a crutial question: *Is it actually possible to use CFile objects in combination with delayed rendering?* Nevertheless, I can access the delay-rendered data through a global memory pointer.

Any help/suggestion very appreciated, many thanks in advance :-)

Tomas

Answer (score 1):

Well, it makes sense after all - the CFile::m_hFile equals to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE as there's no real physical file there, but instad just an abstraction of some non-file data. So **the above code works fine** - it was just that I didn't get further with the testing than checking out the inner file handle, seeing `-1` there.

Problem therefore solved and lesson learned :-)